# dotnet-coverage No code coverage data available. Profiler was not initialized

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage

I am trying to collect my code coverage for my .net core 6 project, I have written some tests and I am planning to upload the results to sonarqube.

I read [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/test-coverage/dotnet-test-coverage/) documentation and decided to go with the dotnet-coverage tool, for some reason I can't get the code coverage, running the command

```
dotnet tool run dotnet-coverage collect 'dotnet test' -f xml -o 'tests/TestResults/coverage.xml'
```

gives me the following message `No code coverage data available. Profiler was not initialized.` and creates an empty coverage.xml file, I am using a macos with m1 processor, not sure if that makes any difference.

I am aware of other ways of generating code coverage but I am curious as to what that message means.

Comment: do you get  this error along with sonarqube setup or while running as a standalone cmd ?

Comment: I am running sonarqube with docker compose and using dotnet sonarqube scanner tool

Answer (score 2):

It works perfectly for me. just few changes.

I ran cmd:

```
dotnet-coverage collect dotnet test -f xml -o coverage.xml
```

[image]

and it is also uploaded to sonarqube

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Are you using a Mac M1 processor? I get the same issue as the OP and can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: No I used windows

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run the command from the question on windows but I needed to add the following to my steps to be able to run it successfully in a Linux environment.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libxml2
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue on GitHub Actions pipeline. In order to resolve this I had to add installation of the following packages prior to running the analysis, which fixed it for me:

```
- name: Install dependencies
    run: apt-get update && apt-get install -y libxrender1 libfontconfig libxext6 libc6 libxml2
```

Please note that we run our pipelines on Debian, so your package names may vary if you run on a different OS flavor